# Parse xml type file

Tags: python, xml, tags, elementtree

I have an xml-type document:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="title" value="Donny" />
        <add key="updaterApplication" value="Updater v4.3" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And I need to modify a particular entry, e.g. the `value="Updater v4.3"` to `value="Updater v4.4"`, when add `key="updaterApplication"`.

I tried with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(my_file_name)
root = tree.getroot()
tkr_itms = root.findall('appSettings')
for elm in tkr_itms[0]:
    print(elm)
    print(elm.attributes)
    print(elm.value)
    print(elm.text)
```

But can't get to address the content between `'< ... />'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you figured out that the "content between '< ... />' " are attributes.

An alternative to iterating over `add` elements and checking the value of the `key` attribute is to check the attribute value in a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates).

Example...

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("my_file_name")
root = tree.getroot()
root.find('appSettings/add[@key="updaterApplication"]').attrib["value"] = "Updater v4.4"

print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

**Output**

```xml
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="title" value="Donny" />
        <add key="updaterApplication" value="Updater v4.4" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

[See here for more info on XPath in ElementTree.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind ... :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(my_file_name)
root = tree.getroot()
for elm in root.iter('add'):
    if elm.attrib['key']=='updaterApplication':
        elm.attrib['value'] = 'Updater v4.4'
    print(elm.attrib)
```